# BottomNavigationView height issue when changing status bar transparency in Android app material 3

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, material-components-android, android-statusbar

I'm working on an Android app where I want to change the status bar transparency in a DetailFragment. I've implemented a function transparentStatusBar to achieve this. When I call transparentStatusBar(true) in the DetailFragment, the status bar becomes transparent, but when I press the return button to go back to the previous fragment, the height of the bottomNavigationView gets messed up.

Here's the code for the transparentStatusBar function:

```
fun Activity.transparentStatusBar(transparent: Boolean) {
    if (transparent) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    } else {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.parseColor("#F8FDFF")
    }
}
```

And in the DetailFragment, I'm calling it like this:

```
requireActivity().transparentStatusBar(true)
```

Here's a before and after screenshot of the bottomNavigationView:

[bottomNavigationView before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AzIB.jpg)

[bottomNavigationView next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVgWC.jpg)

It seems that setting WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) is causing the issue. How can I prevent this issue and maintain the correct bottomNavigationView height when changing the status bar transparency in the DetailFragment?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you after changing the status bar and navigation bar transparent, and I solved this problem by reducing the bottom padding of bottomNaviagtionView.

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.post(() -> {
            int start = binding.bottomNavigationView.getPaddingStart();
            int top = binding.bottomNavigationView.getPaddingTop();
            int end = binding.bottomNavigationView.getPaddingEnd();
            int bottom = binding.bottomNavigationView.getPaddingBottom();
            binding.bottomNavigationView.setPadding(start, top, end, bottom - getNavigationBarHeight(this));
        });
```

here is the method to get navigation bar height.

```
public int getNavigationBarHeight() {
    int navigationBarHeight = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        navigationBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return navigationBarHeight;
}
```